# Unable to replace a pattern in csv file using unix command

Tags: csv, unix

I have a csv file with below values, I am trying to replace the value "^@" using SED command but getting error message "Pattern not found".

Value:

```
^@#uiuiuiui^@
^@#uiuiuiui^@
^@#uiuiuiui^@
^@#uiuiuiui^@
^@#uiuiuiui^@
```

Attempt:

```
sed 's/^@/$/g' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to backslash the `^` char.  In a regular expression, it means "starts with".  It is an operator.  Since you want to explicitly replace it, backslash it.

So:

```
sed 's/\^@/$/g' file.csv
```

Comment: I tried the option but still it is not replacing the value. The same error mgs "Pattern not found" is displayed.

Comment: I put your sample content in a file and ran it, it works.  Make sure your file has unix line feeds (dos2unix file.csv).

Comment: I am trying it in Mac.